# How to optimize posts query in wordpress

Tags: posts, query, optimization

basically, I'm trying to optimize this query we have more than 100K blogs and I need to make it faster now it takes Load time (07.46 s).

```
<?php
                    if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
                    elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
                    else { $paged = 1; }
                            $query = new WP_Query(array(
                                'date_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                                'year' => date( 'Y' )-2,
                                                'compare'   => '>=',
                                        ),
                                ),
                                'posts_per_page'   => 10,
                                'paged' => $paged
                            ));
                            while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <article id="post-<?php the_id() ?>" class="card bg-light text-dark card-blog">

                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large',['class'=>'card-img-top']); ?>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <span class="card-meta">
                                <time datetime="<?php echo strtotime(the_time('F j, Y')); ?>"><?php echo the_time('F j, Y'); ?></time> | <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                            </span>
                            <h3 class="card-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <p class="lead"><?php  echo substr(get_the_excerpt(),0,50).'...'; ?></p>
                            <div class="btn-container">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More<?php gpi_sprite('arrow-right'); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </section>
                <?php
                    $pages = paginate_links( array(
                        'format' => '?page=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
                        'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
                        'type'=>'array',
                    ) );
                ?>
```

the above query grabbing all blog posts 10 posts per page but I show only the latest 2 years and this takes much expected than I imagine **I appreciate any help**

Comment: is this the primary query on the page? Is there a reason you're not using `pre_get_posts`? By doing it on the page you're doubling the number of queries as you're throwing away the main query

Comment: yes this is a primary query, can you explain how to use pre_get_posts ?

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) provides enough information to serve as a decent introduction. But even so - querying for 10 posts should not take 7 seconds even on a moderately large site. Perhaps take a look at using something like Query Monitor or LAPS to get better idea of where the bottlenecks are, as well as a front-end report like Pagespeed Insights just to confirm that the performance issue is indeed server-side.

Comment: This can't be a primary query as it's not the main query, and you used a custom `WP_Query` object. You should use the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the main query instead of discarding it and replacing it with a second custom query. Then you could use a standard post loop instead of a custom post loop, and your pagination would then work with normal function calls without workarounds. Also is 7 seconds the time of the query or the time of the entire page load? Note that you need a _specific_ question that someone can write an answer to that can be marked as correct

Comment: Remember, `new WP_Query` is not how you customize the posts that WP shows. It's a brand new query for a new additional post loop on top of what WP has already done. The main query is still there, and still influences things. E.g. if your query has 10 pages, but the main query has 9, then page 10 might give a 404, and plugins may not acknowledge that a 10th page exists, or report info based on the main query, not your custom query

Comment: [Asked and answered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668049/how-to-optimize-posts-query-in-wordpress/68674101#68674101).